# Hauptsätze mit welche

Tags: pronoun, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

**Sätze mit "welche":**

**Beispiel**

> L-Citrullin wird im Körper zu L-Arginin umgewandelt, welches über weitere Stationen zu Stickstoffmonooxid (NO) umgewandelt wird, was uns geweitete Gefäße und damit Pump beschert.

So wie ich es verstehe, bezieht sich "welches" hier auf das Subjekt (L-Citrullin). Kann man das Subjekt also nicht auch mit "es" anstatt "welches" ersetzen?

Hinweis: Ich lerne selber Deutsch, und habe gerade die Hauptsätze mit "welch" entdeckt. Falls Sie etwas erklären möchten, können Sie es gerne auf Englisch erklären.

Comment: Ich habe ein paar Grammatikfehler korrigiert, bzw. Sätze so umgeschrieben, dass es "natürlicher" klingt. Wenn du Fragen dazu hast, schreib einfach einen Kommentar mit @Iris

Comment: Was heißt *Pump* in diesem Zusammenhang? Kenn ich nur als umgangssprachlich für Schulden, oder im Zusammenhang mit Pumpen, was hier nicht passt.

Comment: @guidot Du gehst nicht ins Gym, oder? http://www.got-big.de/Blog/pump-effekt-muskelpump/

Answer (score 5):

"Welche" bezieht sich in dem von dir genannten Beispiel auf L-Arginin. Das herauszufinden ist nicht möglich indem man schlicht die die Felxionsform betrachtet, allerdings legt die logische Struktur des Satzes einen Prozess nahe; auf Englsich übersetzt würde man in etwa so formulieren:

> L-Citrullin gets converted to L-Arginin, which gets converted...

usw. Dieser Prozess ist linear dargestellt, also ist es höchst unwahrscheinlich, dass sich "welches" auf L-Citrullin bezieht. Zu deiner Frage: nein, da "es" kein Relativpronomen ist, und in konkretem Fall wird ein Relativpronomen durch den logischen Gedankengang benötigt.

Wenn "welches" sich auf das Subjekt beziehen würde, würde es ohnehin direkt hinter das Subjekt gestellt worden sein. Beispiel:

> L-Citrullin, welches letztlich über weitere Stationen zu NO umgewandelt wird, wird im Körper zuerst zu L-Arginin umgewandelt.

Comment: Ok aber Welche Können wir einfach "die" benützen ?  L-Citrullin wird im Körper zu L-Arginin umgewandelt, die über weitere Stationen zu Stickstoffmonooxid (NO) umgewandelt wird,

Comment: First of, it would be "das", not "die", as L-Citrullin is a word with a neuter grammatical gender. Also, as I explained, "welche" builds up a certain connection in this sentence. "Das", in the place where you put "die", would definitely not be wrong, but alter the impact of the sentence heavily as well as not be common in written as well as spoken German flow of speech.

Comment: Deine Muttersprache ist Deutsch (behauptest du jedenfalls in deinem Profil). Du hast eine Frage gelesen, die von einem/einer Deutschen in Deutsch geschrieben wurde, sie wurde in einem Forum veröffentlicht, dass die deutsche Sprache zum Inhalt hat, und die Frage selbst dreht sich um einen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache. Auch meine Muttersprache ist Deutsch. Warum um alles in Welt muss ich dann Kenntnisse einer Fremdsprache auspacken, um deine Antwort zu verstehen? Von mir bekommst du -1 für's Antworten in der falschen Sprache.

Comment: Sollte es in den Richtlinien dieser Stack Exchange-Abteilung stehen, Fragen möglichst immer in derselben Sprache zu beantworten in der sie gestellt werden (bitte verlinken), entschuldige ich mich und bearbeite es entsprechend.
Ansonsten sehe ich dies eher als Schönheitsfehler denn wirklichen Grund zum downvote an.

Comment: @Locké Was du hier über ›welches‹ und ›das‹ sagst, ist schlicht falsch. In der gesprochenen Sprache gibt es nur eine Art von Relativpronomen (der/die/das), und jeder Text, der von professionellen Verfassern kommt, die selber viel lesen, verwendet auch nur das.

Comment: @deponensvogel Beziehst du dich auf die Antwort oder auf einen Kommentar?

Comment: @Locké, meta: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question

Comment: @Iris Vielen Dank, werde die Antwort bei gelegenheit umschreiben!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast du kannst deinen Downvote entfernen.

Answer (score -3):

›Welcher/welche/welches‹ ist ein Interrogativ-/Fragepronomen:

> **Welches** Pronomen meinst du?

Irgendwann einmal ist es in die Rolle des Relativpronomens geschlüpft:

> Das Pronomen, **das** ich meine --› Das Pronomen, **welches** ich meine.

Diese Verwendung ist aber eine ziemlich bildungsbürgerliche. Sie findet sich deshalb bei Autoren, die feiner klingen wollen, als sie eigentlich sind. Gute Schriftsteller verwenden das einzige Relativpronomen, das in der gesprochenen Sprache anerkannt ist: der/die/das.

Die Merkregel lautet: Wenn man ›welches/dieses/jenes‹ einsetzen kann, kommt ›das‹, ansonsten ›dass‹.

Comment: Lies dir noch einmal die Frage durch. Roxy fragte, ob man "welches" durch "es" ersetzen kann. Deine "Antwort" ist im Kontext der Frage betrachtet nicht passend.

Comment: Die Antwort ist zu schwarz/weiß. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen#Welcher.2C_welche.2C_welches) sagt: _"[welcher, welche, welches] wird insbesondere verwendet, um Wortwiederholungen durch Zusammentreffen von der, die, das mit einem gleichlautenden Artikel oder durch Relativsätze zweiter Ordnung zu vermeiden."_

Comment: @Iris Weil manche Autoren noch immer das Ammenmärchen von der Erlebniserzählung im Kopf haben, dass Wortwiederholungen schlecht sind.

Answer (score -4):

You can use "dass" with two "S", meaning **"that"**.

The grammar rule I know says: if you can exchange "das/dass" (at this time still unknown if spelled with one or two "S") with "dieses", "jenes" or "welches", it's spelled with one "S", i.e. you write "das". If you can't, it's spelled with two "S", i.e. you have to write "dass".

By the way, using "es" in this case is grammatically wrong.

Comment: 1. "Welch" **does** exist. 2. The question wasn't about "dass" and it's certainly not correct in the example. I'm wondering why you're coming up with that, anyway.

Comment: Sorry you are right....  You can @

Comment: say" Welch Hohn"

Comment: But that is more poetic...